# What is the right way to call function from a class that does not implement the function class?

Tags: c#

Simple question, Lets say I have Two Classes, Logic and UI,
Logic and Ui are in different Projects.
I need to trigger a function through the logic class.

```
//implements the ui logic, and have an instance of Logic

Class Ui{
Logic l = new Logic();

  public void Draw(){

  //using the logic information that we have through the instance will render the data.

  }
}

//Implement the logic and does not know the UI

Class Logic{

// after end some calculations need to trigger Draw() in the Ui.
}
```

What are the correct ways to implement this?
I thought maybe sign the function to a delegate or event I was not sure about this and I want to be sure about the correct way.

Comment: You would have to pass an instance of a Parent to Child.... Would be better if you gave a [mcve] of what you are actually trying to accomplish, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer  through the constructor? would it be a bad way?

Comment: Or a setter. Or a method with a Parent parameter. Not sure why that would be bad. You need an instance to call an instance method.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I edited the question.

Comment: Your example already shows `Logic l = new Logic();` in the `UI` class - what's wrong with that? I am a bit unclear on what the actual question here is

Comment: @CoolBots I need to call Draw() from the Logic class that does not have instance

Comment: @AmitKahlon why??? Why can't the `Logic` class complete it's calculations and then *whatever called it from the UI class* calls `Draw()`?

Comment: @CoolBots logic* runs a timer that every tick of his will calc some stuff, after that tick is over I want it to call draw, I'm looking for the correct way do to this considering rules like abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two easy ways to achieve this:

- with an instance of `Parent` passed to `Child`
- use inheritance and a virtual method in `Parent` but do not override it in `Child`

The first one can be achieved like this:

```
class Parent {
    Child c = new Child(this);

    public void Func(){ ... }
}

public class Child() 
{
    private Parent _parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public void SomeRandomMethod() 
    {
        if (_parent != null)
            _parent.Func();
    }
}
```

The second option would look like this:

```
class Parent {
    Child c = new Child();

    public virtual void Func(){ ... }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public void SomeRandomMethod()
    {
        Func(); //because the child hasn't overridden this the method in the parent will get called
    }    
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your updated requirements, here is a (very!) rough semi-pseudocode example using a delegate that is injected into the `Logic` class. There are a number of ways this code could be structured. I've also assumed that you'll need to pass multiple parameters to the `Draw()` function so I've encapsulated that in an object. I also returned a bool from that method - if no return is necessary then change the `Func<DrawingParameters, bool>` to `Action<DrawingParameters>`.

```
public class Ui
{

    public Ui()
    {
        var l = new Logic() { DrawingMethod = Draw } ;
    }

    public bool Draw(DrawingParameters dp)
    {
        //do your drawing
        return true;
    }
}

public class Logic
{
    public Func<DrawingParameters, bool> DrawingMethod { private get; set; }

    public void DoCalculationsAndDraw()
    {
        var drawingParameters = new DrawingParameters();

        //do your calculations, set values in drawingParameters...

        DrawingMethod?.Invoke(drawingParameters);
    }
}

public class DrawingParameters
{
    public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Point EndPoint { get; set; }

    //etc.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I was looking for a way that the the child would not implement the parent at all, something like a delegate which the parent would have to sign the function to the child.
how would much appreciate if you check my new example and give me an answer.

Comment: @AmitKahlon I've updated based on your new example.

Comment: thanks, thats what I was looking for